# Given n points, show there is a unique polynomial through all of them

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

if x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>,..., x<sub>n</sub> are distinct points in [a,b] and $A$ = { a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>,..., a<sub>n</sub> } ∈ R<sup>n+1</sup>, show there is a unique polynomial $p$<sub>A</sub> of degree at most "n" such that $p$<sub>A</sub>(x<sub>j</sub>) = a<sub>j</sub> for each "j".

Then, show that there is a constant $M$ such that for all "a",  ||$p$<sub>a</sub>||<sub>∞</sub> ≤ $M$||$A$||<sub>2</sub>.

In the second part, ||.||<sub>∞</sub> is the "sup norm" or "max norm" on the space of continuous functions $C$([a,b]).

Comment: $\| (a_0,\ldots , a_n)\|_2 = \sqrt{a_0^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}$.

Comment: The unique polynomial is called the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). You can show that it exists simply by constructing it.

Comment: you should ask dr. bodmann